# read and jump lines from a file C

Tags: c, string, buffer, stdio

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  FILE* file = fopen("questions-words.txt", "r"); 
  char line[256];

  while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file) != NULL) {                
    if (line[0]==":") {
      continue;
    }
    printf("%s", line);   
  }
  fclose(file);
  return 0;
}
```

Hi I trying to print the lines of a file and jump the ones that start with  a ":" but it doesnt seem to work.
Also I can't print line[0] it gives a warning because "line is type int"

Comment: The code shouldn't compile `if (line[0]==":"){` (or, at minimum, should generate warnings).  You can't compare a character with a string; use `':'` instead.  Heed compiler warnings — the compiler knows a lot more about C than you do, and if it warns, you should assume it is right and should fix your code so it doesn't warn you about it.  (You should also check that the `fopen()` succeeds before using `file`; your program is likely to crash if it fails to open the file. … added while user1320881 was adding the same comment.)

Comment: Also always test if opening the file succeeded.

Comment: Thank you very much.
I just wanted to post the code the most simplified as I could but thanks for the tip on that too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>


    int main(int argc, char* argv[])
    {


        FILE* file = fopen("questions-words.txt", "r"); /* should check the result */
        if (file==NULL){
            return-1;
        }
        char line[256];
        char first[20],second[20],third[20],fourth[20],temp[20];


        while (! feof(file)) {
            fscanf(file,"%s \t", first);
            if (!strcmp(first,":")){
                fscanf(file,"%s \t",temp);
            continue;
                }

                fscanf(file,"%s \t", second);
                fscanf(file,"%s \t", third);
                fscanf(file,"%s \t", fourth);
                printf("%s %s %s %s \n", first, second, third, fourth);



        }
                fclose(file);

                return 0;
    }
```

@ameyCu 's answer is better but since I knew each line had 4 words I also find this solution (just in case is helpful for somene)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of this -

```
if (line[0]==":"){
```

use this -

```
if (line[0]==':'){   // note the single quotes
```

**Note** - `';'` is of type `int` (as pointed out by  Cool Guy) unlike `":"` which is a string literal .

Comment: `':'` is of type `int`, not `char`.

Comment: @CoolGuy Correct its a character literal, my bad.